# util_1.promisify is not a function error using googleapis package

Tags: typescript, cypress, google-apis-explorer

I'm using googleapis inside my Cypress project as a util to interact with some Gmail messages. I just installed the library and implemented the following code:

```ts
const oAuth2Client: Auth.OAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
  credentials.client_id,
  credentials.client_secret,
  credentials.redirect_uri
);

export class GmailAPIHandler {
  
  constructor() {
    oAuth2Client.setCredentials({
      refresh_token: REFRESH_TOKEN,
      scope: SCOPES,
    });
  }

  getLastEmailSnippet() {
    const gmail = google.gmail({ version: "v1", auth: oAuth2Client });
    var response: GmailMainResponse;

    gmail.users.messages.list(
      {
        userId: "me",
      },
      (getEmailListErr, getEmailListRes) => {
        if (getEmailListErr)
          return console.log("The API returned an error ", getEmailListErr);
        response = <GmailMainResponse>(<unknown>getEmailListRes);
        return response.resp[0].data.snippet;
      }
    );
  }
}
```

When the project is compiling the `util_1.promisify is not a function` error is shown.

I'm using typescrypt, node version 14.15.1 and npm version 6.14.8.

This is the traceback:

```plaintext
The following error originated from your test code, not from Cypress.

  > util_1.promisify is not a function

When Cypress detects uncaught errors originating from your test code it will automatically fail the current test.

Cypress could not associate this error to any specific test.

We dynamically generated a new test to display this failure.
node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/identitypoolclient.js:25:1
  23 | // src/index.ts.
  24 | // Fallback to void function to avoid promisify throwing a TypeError.
> 25 | const readFile = util_1.promisify((_a = fs.readFile) !== null && _a !== void 0 ? _a : (() => { }));
     | ^
  26 | const realpath = util_1.promisify((_b = fs.realpath) !== null && _b !== void 0 ? _b : (() => { }));
  27 | const lstat = util_1.promisify((_c = fs.lstat) !== null && _c !== void 0 ? _c : (() => { }));
  28 | /** 
View stack trace
 Print to console
    at Object.1909../baseexternalclient (node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/identitypoolclient.js:25:1)
    at o (node_modules/browser-pack/_prelude.js:1:1)
    at eval (node_modules/browser-pack/_prelude.js:1:1)
    at Object.1906../awsclient (node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/externalclient.js:18:1)
    at o (node_modules/browser-pack/_prelude.js:1:1)
    at eval (node_modules/browser-pack/_prelude.js:1:1)
    at Object.eval (node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js:29:1)
    at Object.eval (https://portal-test.redibs.com/__cypress/tests?p=cypress\integration\features\regression-test\onboarding\onboarding_successful_registration.feature:177228:5)
    at Object.1907.../crypto/crypto (https://portal-test.redibs.com/__cypress/tests?p=cypress\integration\features\regression-test\onboarding\onboarding_successful_registration.feature:177228:18)
    at o (node_modules/browser-pack/_prelude.js:1:1)
From previous event:
    at runScriptsFromUrls (https://portal-test.redibs.com/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:160060:98)
    at Object.runScripts (https://portal-test.redibs.com/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:160074:11)
    at $Cypress.onSpecWindow (https://portal-test.redibs.com/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:149502:19)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, finally I resolved my issue. It seems like the issue was due to cypress always is executed in the browswer and that API library needs to be executed from node, so I have create a plugin based on this [cypress plugins](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/plugins-guide#Use-Cases) documentation in order to be able to execute the google API tasks from node. Also I added that plugin in my test using [cy.task](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/task) command. I hope this information can be useful.